# C# waiting for data from a NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networking, stream

I'm working on a asynchronous TCP server class that uses a `TcpListener` object. I'm using the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` method for the `TcpListener`, and when the callback fires and `EndAcceptTcpClient`, I get a `TcpClient` object.  In order to receive and send with this `TcpClient` I need to use the `NetworkStream` provided by the client object.

The way I've been using the `NetworkStream` feels wrong though.  I call `BeginRead` and a callback to eventually use `EndRead`, but this requires that I use `byte[]` buffer.  This has worked fine for me so far, but I have to wonder if there is a cleaner way of doing things.  My current flow is so as follows: [receive data into a byte[] buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx), [throw data into a `MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx), [use a `BinaryReader` to get the data that I'm passing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k01zeat(v=vs.110).aspx), and then I can ultimately get what I need for my protocol.

Is there a more elegant way to get from `NetworkStream` to `BinaryReader` (and ultimately `BinaryWriter` as I'm going to pass data back similarly as I received it)?  It feels wasteful that I must first dump it into a `byte[]`, then into a `MemoryStream` (does that copy the data?), then finally be able to create a reader/writer object.

I've looked into simply creating a `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` using the `NetworkStream`, but from what I've gathered, those objects require a stream with data previously available.  It seems like I just need to have some way to be notified that the `NetworkStream` has data available without reading into a buffer.  Perhaps I am mistaken and this is exactly how `NetworkStreams` are supposed to be used.  It just seems like things could be a lot more streamlined if I didn't have to copying buffers from one stream into another.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the source in question:

```
public class Server
{
  TcpListener listener;
  const int maxBufferSize = 0xFFFF;
  byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[maxBuffersize];

  public Server(IPAddress address, int port)
  {
    listener = new TcpListener(address, port);
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    listener.Start();
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAccept, listener);
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    listener.Stop();
  }

  private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    TcpListener listener = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    client.GetStream().BeginRead(clientBuffer, 0, maxBufferSize, OnReceive, client);    
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAccept, listener);
  }

  private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    TcpClient client = ar.AsyncState as TcpClient;
    int len = client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
    if (len == 0)
    {
      client.Close();
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(len == maxBufferSize ? clientBuffer : clientBuffer.Take(len).ToArray());
      MemoryStream outStream = DoStuff(inStream); //Data goes off to the app at this point and returns a response stream
      client.GetStream().Write(outStream.ToArray(), 0, outStream.Length);
      inStream.Dispose();
      outStream.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

My question revolves around what happens in `OnReceive`.  You'll see that I finish the read operation with `EndRead`, at which point I can now retrieve the data from the byte[] field of the Server class.  My concern is that the time spent copying data from the NetworkStream into an array, and then into a MemoryStream is wasteful (at least it feels that way, perhaps C# handles this stuff efficiently?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use :             byte[] rxData = new byte[20];
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("filename", FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            bWriter.Write(rxData);  The BinaryWriter automatically writes to the Filestream.

Comment: That works fine and all jdweng, but it doesn't address NetworkStreams.  I'm trying to find a nice simple solution like this that works for NetworkStreams.  That solution works for FileStreams because all the data that will ever be in the stream is available after instantiation, but not NetworkStreams.

Comment: It'd be great to see some code.

Comment: The code will work fine if placed in the Async Event where TCP is received where the OP already has his code.